# changing locale in app on Android 2.2 platform (on Android 4.0 is ok) in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like to change my app locale programmatically. I use the following code to do the task which is in `onCreate()` method of Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();

    Configuration config= new Configuration();
    config.locale = new Locale("fr"); //use French locale
    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);

    //following code will navigate among fragments
    ...
}
```

My app only has **one Activity** which hosts **several fragments**.

If I run my app on **Android 4.0** platform, **it is working nicely**, every fragment display with "French" language.

But if I run on **Android 2.2** platform, **only the first fragment** display in French language, the next replaced fragment still show English (my phone setting use English locale).

Why it works only on Android 4.0 platform ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some bug in Android 2.x

Because if you change locale not in `onCreate()` but in `createMenu()` or inside some `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` it will work.

It is workaround but try to call some event after start your app and change locale in it.